# How to override adminhtml phtml in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, shipping, template, phtml

How to override `vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/view/form.phtml` file in magento2

Answer (score 7):

Create `adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml` file in `app\code\CompanyName\ExtensionName\view\adminhtml\layout\`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="sales_shipment_view">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">CompanyName_ExtensionName::form.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Put `form.phtml` file `app\code\CompanyName\ExtensionName\view\adminhtml\templates\` folder.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Hi Sanjay, Please explain how to override vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/create/items.phtml file?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to override this template file- then use bellow XML:-

```
vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/view/form.phtml
```

---

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<block class="Magento\Shipping\Block\Adminhtml\View" name="sales_shipment_view">
    <referenceBlock name="form">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">CompanyName_moduleName::form.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</block>
</page>
```

---

I have resolve my blank page issue and it's Working Fine.