# Want to know how to override any file in magento2 like magento1 (Copy core file to local directory)

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I try to override

> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\vinm2\vendor\magento\module-shipping\view\adminhtml\templates\view\form.phtml

So I copy it to

> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\vinm2\app\design\frontend\Vend\vision\Magento_Shipping\templates\view\form.phtml

I also tried

> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\vinm2\app\design\frontend\Vend\vision\Magento_Shipping\view\adminhtml\templates\view\form.phtml

but not working.

can any one let me know what is wrong here?

**Updated:**

As per suggestion here i create module..

D:\XAMPP\htdocs\vinm2\app\code\Bkjain\Shipp have below files & directory

1: etc
2: view
3: registration.php

etc have module.xml with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Bkjain_Shipp" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

2: view have adminhtml--

```
                    -layout -> adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml

                    -templates -> form.phtml
```

---

adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml  have below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="sales_shipment_view">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Bkjain_Shipp::form.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

form.phtml have default code but it not display anything.. IF i delete content of that file & just write echo then it show echo value ..

[image]

Comment: I want to know how to override any file from vendor directory to theme directory..

Comment: You cant override adminhtml template file into your theme, you have to create module for that.

Comment: follow this link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161004/how-to-override-adminhtml-phtml-in-magento2

Comment: Thank you @Rajkumar.E .. I will check and post here if i have any issue..

Comment: Hi file is override but the content of form.phtml not show .. If i delete the content of file and just simple echo anything then it will show .. but default content not load of that file..

Answer (score 0):

check the below code.

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Theme>/<name_theme>/Magento_<module_name>/templates
```

Example

vendor file path:

```
app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

Your file path:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Theme>/<name_theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

it is only for frontend template files.

Clear cache